# Does Gmail provide a way to see a hash of an email?

Tags: gmail, authentication

Does Gmail provide a way to see a hash that they say represents the sum of all data within a given email?

Answer (score 2):

Not *exactly* a hash, but every email has a unique ID.  This value is accessible through the `X-GM-MSGID` email header.

```
 X-GM-MSGID: 1459153717434291429
```

This value, when converted to base-16, is `143ff493385c94e5`, and with this we can directly link to said email: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/143ff493385c94e5.  (note: that link won't actually work unless you're logged in as me)

Comment: +1 Thanks, aware of the IDs, though as you know, it does not appear to be a hash; that said, it would likely be of if storing hashes.

Comment: No Problem.  They're not strictly hashes, but I've used them many times because all I really want is a guaranteed unique string, and they fit the bill.  (and, technically, hash functions don't)